# Using the repository functions in the viewModel with coruntineScope in android Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Working with Androind and Room for the first time, and i was able to follow a few codelabs and tutorials to achieve inserting and showing a list of my entities, but i cant seem to be able to use my other Repository methods in my ViewModel due to a type mismatch, here is my ViewModel file

```
class CustomerViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    // The ViewModel maintains a reference to the repository to get data.
    private val repository: CustomerRepository
    // LiveData gives us updated words when they change.
    val allCustomers: LiveData<List<Customer>>

    init {
        // Gets reference to Dao from db to construct
        // the correct repo.
        val customerDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(application).customerDao()
        repository = CustomerRepository(customerDao)
        allCustomers = repository.getCustomers()
    }

    fun insert(customer: Customer) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(customer)
    }

}
```

and im trying to add a method like

```
fun find(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        return repository.getCustomerByLocalId(id)
    }
```

but the ide says there's a type mismatch here? `Required: Customer, Found: Job`

here is my repository:

```
class CustomerRepository(private val customerDao: CustomerDao) {


    fun getCustomers(): LiveData<List<Customer>> = customerDao.getAlphabetizedCustomers()

    suspend fun getCustomerByLocalId(local_Id: Int): Customer =
        customerDao.customerByLocalId(local_Id)

    suspend fun insert(customer: Customer) {
        customerDao.insert(customer)
    }


    companion object {

        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile
        private var instance: CustomerRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(customerDao: CustomerDao) =
            instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: CustomerRepository(customerDao).also { instance = it }
            }
    }
}
```

methods in CustomerDao

```
@Query("SELECT * from customers ORDER BY name ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedCustomers(): LiveData<List<Customer>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(customer: Customer)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE local_id = :localId")
    suspend fun customerByLocalId(localId: Int): Customer
```

**EDIT**
I tried @lena-bru 's suggestion but the error is still there, there appears to be 2 different ones, the type mismatch and that there should not be a return. are you supposed to create this method in a different location?
[The IDE error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn2v6.png)

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
   fun find(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        return repository.getCustomerByLocalId(id)
   }
```

to this:

```
   fun find(id: Int): Customer = viewModelScope.launch {
       withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
         repository.getCustomerByLocalId(id)
       }
   }
```

Your find method as defined above is void, it needs to return type Customer

Also you need to provide a context, and remove the return keyword

Comment: thanks!, thats one mistake but the mismatch is still there, it says: Required: Customer, Found: Job

Comment: can you post the full wording of the error? maybe there is a line number?

Comment: @AmrSabbagh see the edit, i added "withContext" see if that helps you

Comment: i added a photo of the IDE error with the last edit, there was no change in it when i added withContext

Comment: did you remove the return?

Comment: yes, the return error is gone but the type mismatch is still there